# Is it still advisable to pass functors to STL instead of functions?

Tags: c++, stl

In Effective STL, Scott Meyers back in 2001 advises:

> Item 46: Consider function objects instead of functions as algorithm parameters

In said chapter, he proceeds to explain that `inline operator()` can get inlined into the algorithm's body, but passing a function generally can`t. This is because we are passing a function *pointer* actually.

In support of that I [seem to remember](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Inline.html) that if a function's address is ever taken, the function can't be inlined.

So two questions here. Firstly, is this still true with C++14?

If yes:

- Why is there no mechanism to do this automatically (motivation: declaring a functor is a lot less straightforward and readable, than declaring a function).
- A lambda without capture is convertible to function pointer, while a capturing lambda can only be passed as a functor. Does this mean we need to capture something only for the sake of the stated optimization?

Comment: Just do what ever is most readable and let the compiler/LTO worry about inlining until you find out by measurement that something is too slow for your usecase. If you never heard of LTO, no one cares about the performance of your code anyway,

Comment: You don't need to capture something in lambda, the convertion to function pointer is only done when needed.

Comment: *"if a function's address is ever taken, the function can't be inlined."* the determination isn't made on a per-function basis... you can have both inlined and out-of-line use of the same function from different call sites.  If the address is taken it just means there needs to be an out-of-line version.

Comment: It has more to do with compiler optimization capabilities than standard. A quick  [test](http://goo.gl/W0iptw) shows gcc inlines function call in vector.erase/remove at version 4.7 but does not in 4.6 (both with c++98 option).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> In support of that I seem to remember that if a function's address is ever taken, the function can't be inlined.

You're reading that incorrectly. A function can be inlined into any direct call site, and any indirect call site if the compiler can trace the function pointer. What the GCC manpage is saying that a function that is inlined into every call site will not be emitted as a separate function at all (thus reducing binary size), *unless* its address is taken.

> Firstly, is this still true with C++14?

Yes. Of course, now you would generally write lambdas instead of hand-crafted functors.

> Why is there no mechanism to do this automatically.

It's a matter of the type system. All functions with a given signature have the same type. Thus, an algorithm that is passed a function pointer gets instantiated to one concrete function, and its code just exists once in the compilation model of C++.

Of course, an optimizer can still specialize the function on one particular argument, but that's a more advanced optimization than just inlining a functor. So yes, there is a mechanism, it's just less likely to be used.

> Does this mean we need to capture something only for the sake of stated at top optimization?

No. The conversion to a function pointer is *possible*, but unless you invoke it explicitly, it won't be done when you pass a lambda to an algorithm.

Comment: Thanks for explaining why this is the case. Although **frymode**'s comment could also be the answer as well.

Answer (score 7):

> Is this still true with C++14?

Depends on whether the compiler can inline the whole algorithm. If it can, then it can probably also inline the function call. If not, then the function probably can't be inlined, because the algorithm in that case is instantiated using a function pointer type and so must be able to handle all function pointers of that type.

For instance, g++ can inline a simple algorithm like `std::transform` but not `std::sort`.

> A lambda without capture is convertible to function pointer, while a capturing lambda can only be passed as a functor. Does this mean we need to capture something only for the sake of stated at top optimization?

No. A lambda without capture is still a functor; the algorithm is instantiated using the closure type (the type of the lambda) rather than the function pointer type.

Comment: In short, the advice is still very valid 14 years later.